# How to Reinstall Keyboard in Kubuntu (Wrong Layout) for CSA keyboard (CAN/CSA Z243.200-92) aka: Canadian Multilingual

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, kde, keyboard-layout, locale

**Can I download a new keyboard definition for the layout *Canadian Multilingual (CSA keyboard)* ?**

It's not what I am used to and as one might guess it is pretty annoying.

Even if I select the same configuration settings, the Keyboard is not of the same layout, I do not understand why.

I was using *Fedora 34 (KDE Plasma Shell 5)* and I just switched to *Kubuntu 21.10* I would like to know if there is a way to re-download the files providing the configuration?

This is what I would like to have but I am missing the blue keys and pink keys which are not where they are supposed to be, compared to the different images below:

[image: wikipedia/CSA_keyboard]

[CSA keyboard (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSA_keyboard)

I have a 104 key keyboard that currently has that (wrong) layout but, the name is the one I want to use *Canadian Multilingual*:

[image: 104 key keyboard (wrong) Canadian Multilingual Layout]

Even the so-called *first part* and *second part* are wrong...

*first part*:

[image: so-called first part 104 key keyboard (wrong) Canadian Multilingual Layout]

*second part*:

[image: so-called second part 104 key keyboard (wrong) Canadian Multilingual Layout]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, your suggestion is right. There's no Canadian Standard Association or ANCOR layout yet on Ubuntu. You can create one and upload it, instead of downloading. p.s. You are probably the first person who mentioned CSA! here or Here create new layout. Here A good template, it differs in a few keys.

Comment: If I were to write a code for CSA, I wish I knew which key should type which letter/character. I don't see the differences in a picture on wiki between `-` on `à gauche du 1` and `minus`, little circle on `;` key and `à droite de P`. Where can a linux developer can see the whole document?

Answer (score 0):

This is my essay of re-write a code for the CSA keyboard layout. According to the wiki image and my best guess, these two are a little closer now.

You can insert `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ca`
But I won't edit the image of keyboard, I don't know how.

```
partial
xkb_symbols "csa" {

    name[Group1] = "Canadian Standard";

    key.type[group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC";
    key <TLDE>  { [     slash,  backslash,            bar, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol,     hyphen ]   };
    key <AE01>  { [         1,     exclam,      plusminus, NoSymbol,
              onesuperior, exclamdown ] };
    key <AE02>  { [         2,         at,             at, NoSymbol,
              twosuperior, NoSymbol ]   };
    key <AE03>  { [         3, numbersign,       sterling, NoSymbol,
            threesuperior,   sterling ] };
    key <AE04>  { [         4,     dollar,           currency, NoSymbol,
               onequarter,   Eurosign ] };
    key <AE05>  { [         5,    percent,       currency, NoSymbol,
                  onehalf, threeeighths ]   };
    key <AE06>  { [         6,   question,        notsign, NoSymbol,
            threequarters, fiveeighths ]    };
    key <AE07>  { [         7,  ampersand,      braceleft, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol, seveneighths ] };
    key <AE08>  { [         8,   asterisk,     braceright, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol,  trademark ]   };
    key <AE09>  { [         9,  parenleft,    bracketleft, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol,  plusminus ]   };
    key <AE10>  { [         0, parenright,   bracketright, NoSymbol ] };
    key <AE11>  { [     minus, underscore,        onehalf, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol, questiondown]  };
    key <AE12>  { [     equal,       plus,        notsign, NoSymbol,
            dead_cedilla, dead_ogonek ] };

    key.type[group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC";
    key <AD01>  { [         q,           Q,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
           NoSymbol, Greek_OMEGA ]  };
    key <AD02>  { [         w,           W,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
              lstroke,     Lstroke ]    };
    key <AD03>  { [         e,           E,     Eurosign, NoSymbol,
                   oe,          OE ]    };
    key <AD04>  { [         r,           R,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                paragraph,  registered ]    };
    key <AD05>  { [         t,           T,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
               tslash,      Tslash ]    };
    key <AD06>  { [         y,           Y,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
            leftarrow,         yen ]    };
    key <AD07>  { [         u,           U,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                downarrow,     uparrow ]    };
    key <AD08>  { [         i,           I,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
               rightarrow,    idotless ]    };
    key <AD09>  { [         o,           O,        section, NoSymbol,
               oslash,    Ooblique ]    };
    key <AD10>  { [         p,           P,      paragraph, NoSymbol,
                thorn,       THORN ]    };

    key.type[group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL";
    key <AD11>  { [dead_circumflex, dead_diaeresis, dead_grave, NoSymbol,
                NoSymbol, dead_abovering ]  };

    key.type[group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC";
    key <AD12>  { [  ccedilla,   Ccedilla,     asciitilde, NoSymbol,
           dead_tilde,    dead_macron ] };

    key <AC01>  { [         a,          A,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                   ae,         AE ] };
    key <AC02>  { [         s,          S,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                   ssharp,    section ] };
    key <AC03>  { [         d,          D,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                  eth,        ETH ] };
    key <AC04>  { [         f,          F,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol, ordfeminine ]  };
    key <AC05>  { [         g,          G,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                  eng,        ENG ] };
    key <AC06>  { [         h,          H,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                  hstroke,    Hstroke ] };
    key <AC07>  { [         j,          J,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                U0133,      U0132 ] };
    key <AC08>  { [         k,          K,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                  kra, NoSymbol ]   };
    key <AC09>  { [         l,          L,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                U0140,      U013F ] };

    key.type[group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL";
    key <AC10>  { [ semicolon,          colon,         degree, NoSymbol,
               dead_acute, dead_doubleacute ]   };

    key.type[group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC";
    key <AC11>  { [    egrave,         Egrave,      braceleft, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol,  dead_caron ]  };
    key <BKSL>  { [    agrave,         Agrave,     braceright, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol,  dead_breve ]  };

    key <LSGT>  { [    ugrave,     Ugrave,         degree, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol,   brokenbar ]  };

    key.type[group1]="FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC";
    key <AB01>  { [         z,          Z,  guillemotleft, NoSymbol ]   };
    key <AB02>  { [         x,          X, guillemotright, NoSymbol ]   };

    key.type[group1]="EIGHT_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC";
    key <AB03>  { [         c,          C,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                 cent,   copyright ]    };
    key <AB04>  { [         v,          V,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
          leftdoublequotemark,  leftsinglequotemark ]   };
    key <AB05>  { [         b,          B,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
         rightdoublequotemark, rightsinglequotemark ]   };
    key <AB06>  { [         n,          N,     NoSymbol, NoSymbol,
                U0149,       U266A ]    };
    key <AB07>  { [         m,          M,             mu, NoSymbol,
                   mu,   masculine ]    };
    key <AB08>  { [     comma, apostrophe,           less, NoSymbol,
               Greek_horizbar, multiply ]   };
    key <AB09>  { [    period,   quotedbl,        greater, NoSymbol,
               periodcentered, division ]   };
    key <AB10>  { [    eacute,     Eacute,     dead_acute, NoSymbol,
               NoSymbol, dead_abovedot ]    };

    include "nbsp(level3s)"

    modifier_map Control{ Control_L };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
    include "level5(rctrl_switch)"
};
```

This is a comfirmation and not an answer:

Selecting French Canadian multilingual keyboard layout on Kubuntu

[image: Kubuntu_CSA]

---

Canadian multilingual Keyboard selection in Unity desktop 20.04

[image: Actual_layout]

---

Comparison to the CSA keyboard design,

[image: CSA_wiki]

Most of 3rd Level characters (Key with AltGr) are correct.
And some of 4th Level characters are not correct, on `6`, `a`, `-`, `é` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The Canadian Multilingual Standard (AKA CAN/CSA Z243.200-92) is there on Ubuntu since 2006 at least. CSA keyboard, Canadian French ACNOR and Canadian Multilangual Standard means the same thing.

Check this file with a text editor :

/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ca

then search in this file :

Canadian Multilingual (1st part)

Canadian Multilingual (2nd part)

Both must be installed in this order.
Then you need to configure a shortcut to select the part 2 if you press Ctrl-Right. They are configured as 2 distincts layouts.

If you use Gnome, "Gnome Tweak Tools" must be installed. Then you select Keyboard and Mouse, Keyboard Layout Options, key to change layout, Select Ctrl-Right.

I am not a KDE user but I am sure you can configure your 2 layouts too in this way.

Edit : it's really weird, I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the layout is fine! I just added the euro sign (key 4, E) and moved the currency sign (key 4) to match the Windows version.

> ```
>     partial xkb_symbols "multi" {
>
>     include "ca(fr)"
>
>     name[Group1] = "Canadian Multilingual (1st part)";
>
>     key <TLDE>    { [     slash,  backslash,           bar ]  };
>     key <AE01>    { [         1,     exclam ] };
>     key <AE02>    { [         2,         at ] };
>     key <AE03>    { [         3, numbersign ] };
>     key <AE04>    { [         4,     dollar,           currency ] };
>     key <AE05>    { [         5,    percent, NoSymbol ]   };
>     key <AE06>    { [         6,   question ] };
>     key <AE07>    { [         7,  ampersand,    braceleft ]   };
>     key <AE08>    { [         8,   asterisk,   braceright ]   };
>     key <AE09>    { [         9,  parenleft,  bracketleft ]   };
>     key <AE10>    { [         0, parenright, bracketright ]   };
>     key <AE11>    { [     minus, underscore ] };
>     key <AE12>    { [     equal,       plus,      notsign ]   };
>     
>     key <AD03>  { [         e,          E,          EuroSign ]  };
>     key <AD09>    { [         o,          O ] };
>     key <AD10>    { [         p,          P ] };
>     key <AD11>    { [dead_circumflex, dead_diaeresis, dead_grave  ]   };
>     key <AD12>    { [  ccedilla,   Ccedilla,   asciitilde ]   };
>
>     key <AC10>    { [ semicolon,      colon,     degree ] };
>     key <AC11>    { [    egrave,     Egrave ] };
>     key <BKSL>    { [    agrave,     Agrave ] };
>
>     key <LSGT>    { [    ugrave,     Ugrave ]     };
>     key <AB01>    { [         z,          Z, guillemotleft  ] };
>     key <AB02>    { [         x,          X, guillemotright ] };
>     key <AB08>    { [     comma, apostrophe,           less ] };
>     key <AB09>    { [    period,   quotedbl,        greater ] };
>     key <AB10>    { [    eacute,     Eacute ] }; };
>
> partial xkb_symbols "multi-2gr" {
>
>     name[Group1] = "Canadian Multilingual (2nd part)";
>
>     key <TLDE>    { [    NoSymbol,      hyphen ]  };
>     key <AE01>    { [   onesuperior,  exclamdown ]    };
>     key <AE02>    { [   twosuperior,  NoSymbol ]  };
>     key <AE03>    { [ threesuperior,    sterling ]    };
>     key <AE04>    { [    onequarter,    EuroSign ]    };
>     key <AE05>    { [       onehalf,threeeighths ]    };
>     key <AE06>    { [ threequarters, fiveeighths ]    };
>     key <AE07>    { [    NoSymbol,seveneighths ]  };
>     key <AE08>    { [    NoSymbol,   trademark ]  };
>     key <AE09>    { [    NoSymbol,   plusminus ]  };
>
>     key <AE11>    { [    NoSymbol, questiondown]  };
>     key <AE12>    { [  dead_cedilla, dead_ogonek ]    };
>
>     key <AD01>    { [ NoSymbol,    Greek_OMEGA ]  };
>     key <AD02>    { [    lstroke,        Lstroke ]    };
>     key <AD03>    { [         oe,             OE ]    };
>     key <AD04>    { [  paragraph,     registered ]    };
>     key <AD05>    { [     tslash,         Tslash ]    };
>     key <AD06>    { [  leftarrow,            yen ]    };
>     key <AD07>    { [  downarrow,        uparrow ]    };
>     key <AD08>    { [ rightarrow,       idotless ]    };
>     key <AD09>    { [     oslash,       Ooblique ]    };
>     key <AD10>    { [      thorn,          THORN ]    };
>     key <AD11>    { [ NoSymbol, dead_abovering ]  };
>     key <AD12>    { [ dead_tilde,    dead_macron ]    };
>
>     key <AC01>    { [         ae,          AE ]   };
>     key <AC02>    { [     ssharp,     section ]   };
>     key <AC03>    { [        eth,         ETH ]   };
>     key <AC04>    { [ NoSymbol, ordfeminine ] };
>     key <AC05>    { [        eng,         ENG ]   };
>     key <AC06>    { [    hstroke,     Hstroke ]   };
>     key <AC07>    { [      U0133,       U0132 ]   };
>     key <AC08>    { [        kra,  NoSymbol ] };
>     key <AC09>    { [      U0140,       U013F ]   };
>     key <AC10>    { [ dead_acute, dead_doubleacute ]  };
>     key <AC11>    { [ NoSymbol,  dead_caron ] };
>     key <BKSL>    { [ NoSymbol,  dead_breve ] };
>
>
>     key <LSGT>    { [ NoSymbol,   brokenbar ] };
>
>     key <AB03>    { [       cent,   copyright ]   };
>     key <AB04>    { [  leftdoublequotemark,  leftsinglequotemark ]    };
>     key <AB05>    { [ rightdoublequotemark, rightsinglequotemark ]    };
>     key <AB06>    { [      U0149,       U266A ]   };
>     key <AB07>    { [         mu,   masculine ]   };
>     key <AB08>    { [ Greek_horizbar, multiply ]  };
>     key <AB09>    { [ periodcentered, division ]  };
>     key <AB10>    { [ NoSymbol, dead_abovedot ]   }; };
> ```